# Get two names by ID from another table

Tags: mysql

For a hockey website, I would like to display past results from the home team and of course display the name of the away team. I could make it almost to the end, but I can't the away team name to show up. I receive all needed results from the **RESULTS** table. In there I have the **home_team_id** and the **away_team_id**, which I need to connect to the **TEAM** table in order to show the team name. I could do this with the home team but have no idea how to get the away team names of those found in there.

**results table**

[image: results]

**teams table**

[image: teams]

This is what shows me everything, but no away team name:

```
SELECT results.home_team_id
     , results.away_team_id
     , results.ft_score
     , teams.name 
  FROM results 
  LEFT 
  JOIN teams 
    ON results.home_team_id = teams.team_id 
 WHERE results.home_team_id = '$hteam‘"
```

I have check other post with similar problems/question, but they did not help me. Sorry.

Help would be great! 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join the `teams` table twice with different alias names

```
SELECT results.home_team_id, results.away_team_id, 
       results.ft_score, 
       thome.name as home_name, taway.name as away_name 
FROM results 
LEFT JOIN teams thome ON results.home_team_id = thome.team_id 
LEFT JOIN teams taway ON results.away_team_id = taway.team_id 
WHERE results.home_team_id = '$hteam'
```

Comment: I was there already, but have not defined different names! Thank you so much for your help! Awesome! ThanksThanksThanks!

Comment: In practice, an OUTER JOIN seems unlikely here, but I suppose an opponent might be 'unknown'